# How to embed video on Lead Dyno page template

Tags: html, css, media

the page has a structure like bootstrap: a container row and inside this container we have 3 col-md-4 (on desktop)

I inserted a div in the left column with a video element inside (embedded from youtube).

The video does not adapt to the container dimensions (currently fills the height but does not fill the width of the div container).
And from mobile it looks slim (good width but slim height)

I think I need a media query as this one does not work.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 376px){ 
  .video-block { 
   width: 100%;
   height: 800px;
   }
}
```

I tried to set the width to 800px but it doesn't stick to the top left corner. It sticks to the right form element instead.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzbs6.png)

This is what I could write, modifying the page:

```
html

<div class="video-block"> <figure> <iframe width="100%" height="200px" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/3JX8TivvGyc" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen="">


</iframe></figure> 
</div>
<div>
<p></p>
<h1><strong>BENVENUTO!</strong></h1>
<h2>Partecipa al programma Affiliati</h2>
<h2><strong>Inizia a guadagnare subito!</strong></h2>
<h2><strong>Completa il form e accedi alla Dashboard</strong></h2>
<p></p>
</div>


css

.video-block { 
   width: 100%;
   height:200px;
   background-color: white;
   margin: 5px 0 0 0;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 376px){ 
  .video-block { 
   width: 100%;
   height: 800px;
   }
}
```